# How to restore Windows XP registry after massive erroneous changes?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, system-restore

On my 32-bit Windows XP machine I accidentially imported a .reg file that contained the whole HKCR branch of a 64-bit Windows 2003, now I have my HKCR with lots of redundant and maybe even erroneous data.

The machine is still alive, but I don't know how long it lasts. I guess there's a backup somewhere done by Windows. How do I restore it?

I've found [this guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307545), but it requires a start-up disk which is not very fortunate. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Restore ought to get you back to a point prior to this if you have not disabled it.
Start>Programs>Accessories>System Tools>System Restore.
I would recommend trying it from safemode if it does not run successfully from a normal windows session

Comment: This only works if System Restore was enabled prior to the incident.

Comment: you might note that system restore is off for you and an not an option. I did mention that it won't work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a (free) Live CD of an GNU/Linux operating system, mount your Windows partition and follow [that](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307545) guide of yours (somewhat loosely though).